# Shrink leaflet map's bounds by some padding or ratio

Tags: maps, leaflet

I'd like to shrink a Leaflet map's bounds by some factor (say `50px` or `5%`).

I've tried the following:

```
marginPoint = new L.Point(50, 50);
bounds = map.getPixelBounds();
bottomLeft = bounds.getBottomLeft();
topRight = bounds.getTopRight();

bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
  map.unproject(bottomLeft.subtract(marginPoint)),
  map.unproject(topRight.subtract(marginPoint))
);
```

However, this does not shrink the map, it just moves/translates the current box / current map's bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you `subtract` the same amount to both map containers' corners, the result is that you just shift the map view to the South West (bottom left).

If you are trying to "zoom in" (i.e. the map displays a smaller portion of geographic area, but within the same container dimensions), you would add some pixels to your bottom left corners, and remove some to your top left.

But be noted that you could also simply use the [`latLngBounds.pad()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-pad) (with a negative `bufferRatio` argument) to achieve the same result.

Comment: hmm I'll try this again, but if I remember correctly I did not get pad working with negative number.

Comment: Make sure you do not go below `-1`.

Comment: As mentioned, `LatLngBounds#pad(ratio)` is the way to go, e.g. `getMap().getBounds().pad(-0.95);`

Comment: oh my, there's the problem. From doc I read "given percentage" and I arrogantly fed it integers as 15 for 15%, did not event try floats *facepalm*. Anyway thanks!